# Best way to convert 5PM to 17:00 (12hr to 24hr)

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I would like to be able to convert simple one digit time strings into full timestamp that javascript can understand.

**For Example:**

```
'1PM' => 13:00
'5AM' => 05:00
'7:15PM' => 19:15
etc, etc
```

I want to create bullet proof time input field that will accept any time format thrown at it.

Comment: @Piskvor I tried passing in various date strings into the javascript date object. It seems the only time AM PM is accepted is when in the following format: '1:00 PM 01/01/01'. I want it to be super easy for my users to be able to enter a date. Much like http://doodle.com does.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how bullet proof you want your code to be, you might want to try [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) which is 25.2 KB.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. Seems like a great lib. Is that an expensive resource for a web app? What is the recommended kb limit for JS in an average web app?

Comment: The size is large if you are going some basic stuff, but if you are doing robust stuff with dates, it is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way of doing this with built in JavaScript stuff e.g. Date.  You might have to roll your own e.g. parse the number using JavaScript string functions, then create a Date object and call setHours and setMinutes on it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this as an approximation:

`new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '10:55 PM').toTimeString().split(' ')[0]`

The problem here is that it won't work with the formats in your example. They need to be at least `1:00 PM` (HH:MM and a space between the time and AM/PM)